# How does one start the Powershell ISE with no file open?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

When I launch `powershell_ise.exe`, it defaults to having an open file "Untitled.ps1". Is there a mechanism to ask ISE to launch showing only the prompt?

That is, at the moment when I launch Powershell ISE, I get the following:

[image: Powershell with Empty Document]

whereas I want the following:

[image: Powershell with No Document]

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply launch PowerShell?

Comment: @Tanner: Unicode support, intellisense, faster echo, etc.

Comment: You mean like this: ? http://i.imgur.com/yr3xSRu.png - That's my default Windows 8 powershell ISE, - with just the console?

Answer (score 2):

Super old question at this point, but I just piggy-backed off of [@Windos](https://superuser.com/a/1010915) to come up with a solution that works for me. Since I use ISE-Steroids, there is a feature to persist open files. I didn't want to close all open files on start up, just the Untitled one.

```
foreach($file in $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files) {
  if ($file.DisplayName -like "Untitled*.ps1"){
    $deleteMe = $file
  }
}
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Remove($deleteMe)
```

Trying to remove the file while inside the for loop will give you an enumeration error. If somehow multiple Untitled scripts open at start, `$deleteme` could be an arraylist that adds multiple files with its own `foreach` to remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust your `View` settings in the menu.

- Uncheck Show Script pane
- Uncheck Show Command Add-On
- Uncheck Show Toolbar
- Uncheck other options as desired

[image]

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this. If you close all the ISE instances and start again does it remember?

Comment: It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but I came here looking for an answer so figured I'd give the results of my experimentation.

There is a `$psISE` object which controls ISE settings, the open files, etc. There is a lot you can do with it.

There was a promising looking function:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Clear()
```

Unfortunately, this would simply close all open files (if they were saved) and then open a new untitled file.

I ended up with this:

```
$null = while ($psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files -ne $null) {
    $file = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files[0]
    $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Remove($file)
}
```

Basically, it keeps checking the open files, and closes them until there are none left open. If you were to run this interactively, and had an unsaved document open, you'd be flooded by error pretty quickly as it fails to close then loops back to trying to close it again.

You can then put this in your ISE profile (C:\username\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1). This is what my profile looks like at the moment:

```
$null = while ($psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files -ne $null) {
    $file = $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files[0]
    $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Remove($file)
}

psEdit $PSScriptRoot\snips.ps1
```

Since this runs when launching the ISE, it closes the default untitled file and opens a random file with little snippets I like to refer to instead. You could omit that last line or change it to any file you want to open.

*n.b. that `$null =` is in there to suppress output, and it is faster than piping to `Out-Null` (which I think is important when you're waiting for your editor to load.)*